# Docker commands to run in script from Command Line

Tags: windows, docker, cmd

I need help with following commands to put in script at CMD. I have all setup for docker.

1) Runs at CMD:

docker run --net=host --interactive --tty auvsisuas/interop-client

2) Runs at # on CMD screen

./tools/interop_cli.py --url http://10.10.130.2:8000 --username testuser missions

Reference : https://github.com/auvsi-suas/interop/wiki/Getting-Started#create-container--start-shell
and
https://github.com/auvsi-suas/interop/wiki/Getting-Started#get-missions

If I run individual commands in CMD one after another it works and gives me output. But when I put in script (.bat) file, it only runs 1st command after which # prompt appears on screen but 2nd command does not execute.

What I need:

Script to run Both commands together from CMD

Note: The image is publicly available and can be tried on any docker setup.

[What I want:(This is what happens when I type directly in CMD)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jWVK.jpg)

[My .CMD/BAT file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI275.jpg)

[What happens:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW4CD.jpg) - stops at the # prompt

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: *"it isn't working"* is a bit vague, and screenshots of commands are not terribly useful, either. Can you add some info?

Comment: I just updated sequence of commands and requirements. Kindly check

Comment: Can we see your complete ```Dockerfile```?

Comment: I run Docker Quickstart Terminal after my installation of Docker from internet available reference.It configures various parameters and opens Daemon terminal. Then I open CMD where i run docker command( as mentioned in #1 above ). I do not create any DockerFile independently.  I need o run via CMD which is my requirement and want above  #1 and #2 commands to run together via script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling a .bat etc. from another one, don't forget that the default behaviour is to transfer control to the lower level script and never come back - you need to use 'call' if you want control to return to the top level script after execution of the lower level one.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'another one'? And which lower level script is being transferred to? My first line executes in cmd and the second should work in the # prompt which opens in cmd on execution of the first line.

Comment: OK, never mind. I thought it was worth mentioning this since whenever I have such problems they turn out to have this cause! I assumed you were calling one .bat or .cmd from another, but clearly you aren't.